# Error compilando CyanogenMod

Tags: android, c++, c

Estoy intentando compilar CyanogenMod (un 'fork' de Android) y me surge un extraño código de error cientos de veces en diferentes líneas. El error es el siguiente:

```
external/libcxx/src/strstream.cpp:326: error: no se admite la reubicación 43
external/libcxx/src/system_error.cpp:178: error: no se admite la reubicación 43
external/libcxx/include/stdexcept:112: error: no se admite la reubicación 43
```

He buscado al respecto y no encuentro nada, estoy bastante perdido.

En el código no hay errores, está en la rama estable del proyecto.

El error lo arroja el linker para ser más precisos.

También surge otro error muy similar linkeando con el resto del código ya compilado `archivo.o` que indica:

```
no se admite la reubicación 43 contra el símbolo global vtable for std::__1::moneypunct_byname<wchar_t, false>
```

El mismo error surge muchas veces en diferentes localizaciones:

```
no se admite la reubicación 43 contra el símbolo global std::__1::locale::id::__init()
```

Por otra parte, en el código, algunas de las lineas en las que se dispara el error son:

```
logic_error::~logic_error() _NOEXCEPT {}
//
if (__flag.__state_ != ~0ul)
```

La verdad es que no sé ni qué intentar... Cualquier sugerencia vendría muy bien! Gracias

Comment: no se si esto te ayudara pero en un foro de Google se comenta este link para solucionar un problema similar y este enlaza con una pagina de Cyanogenmod igual te ayuda -> http://review.cyanogenmod.org/#/c/120824/2/build/Android.common_build.mk Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Gracias por tu respuesta, estuve viendo e intenté desactivar clang en favor de gcc pero tampoco me sirvió lamentablemente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por si todavía hay alguno por ahí con el problema
[unsupported reloc 43(Inglés)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36048358/building-android-from-sources-unsupported-reloc-43)

Tiene pinta de ser lo que le pasa al OP en tanto que es un problema de enlazado y es precisamente el mismo error.

Actualización:

Según comentan en el sitio en inglés (y si este es el mismo caso), se trata de aplicar el siguiente [parche](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/223100/).

Indican que para android Lollipop o versiones anteriores es importante añadir el switch -no-integrated-as al aplicar el parche. Para versiones de android Marshmallow en adelante no sería necesario.

Comment: por favor agrega la respuesta en español, no coloques un enlace a otro sitio si haces referencia al sitio agrega el enlace imagina que el que pregunta no sabe ingles